# Why multiple versions of notepadplusplus in Chocolatey

Tags: notepad++, chocolatey

https://chocolatey.org/packages?q=notepadplusplus

"Notepad++ (Install) 7.3.3" looks to be the better one based on the number of downloads, but why is there also "Notepad++ 7.3.3" ?

Comment: May be the install option really install it with shell integration and setup file types and other one is not. Why not you download notepad++ from it's own site?

Comment: Thanks @Biswa. I could test this, but it would be more efficient to look in the underlying install to compare them if that's possible ? Quite a few packages have a similar kind of duplication, so I was wondering if this is some kind of standard. It also looks like someone has helpfully down-voted this question - perhaps trying to indicate it is a stupid question, which surprises me since there isn't yet an answer . . .

Comment: Upvote. It's a valid question, and I also get annoyed by people downvoting  without leaving comments. @Biswa: Chocolatey is a packet manager for windows, making the whole process of browsing to each individual website, downloading installers and going through the install procedure unnecessary.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate, but this question has a more comprehensive answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the Chocolatey FAQ](https://chocolatey.org/faq#what-distinction-does-chocolatey-make-between-an-installable-and-a-portable-application):

> ## What is the difference between packages no suffix as compared to .install .portable?
>
> What is the difference between packages named
> .install (i.  e. autohotkey.install), .portable (i.  e.
> autohotkey.portable) and * (i.  e. autohotkey)?
>
> tl;dr: Nearly 100% of the time, the package with no suffix (autohotkey
> in this example) is going to ensure the *.install. The package without
> the suffix is for both discoverability and for other packages to take
> a dependency on.
>
> Hey, good question! You are paying attention! Chocolatey has the
> concept of virtual packages (coming) and meta packages. Virtual
> packages are packages that represent other packages when used as a
> dependency. Metapackages are packages that only exist to provide a
> grouping of dependencies.
>
> A package with no suffix that is surrounded by packages with suffixes
> is to provide a virtual package. So in the case of git, git.install,
> and git.commandline (deprecated for .portable) – git is that virtual
> package (currently it is really just a metapackage until the virtual
> packages feature is complete). That means that other packages could
> depend on it and you could have either git.install or git.portable
> installed and you would meet the dependency of having git installed.
> That keeps Chocolatey from trying to install something that already
> meets the dependency requirement for a package.
>
> Talking specifically about the *.install package suffix – those are
> for the packages that have a native installer that they have bundled
> or they download and run.
>
> NOTE: the suffix .app has been used previously to mean the same as
> .install. But the *.app suffix is now deprecated and should not be
> used for new packages.
>
> The .portable packages are the packages that will usually result in an
> executable on your path somewhere but do not get installed onto the
> system (Add/Remove Programs). Previously the suffixes .tool and
> *.commandline have been used to refer to the same type of packages.
>
> NOTE: now .tool and .commandline are deprecated and should not be used
> for new packages.
>
> Want more information? See
> http://ferventcoder.com/archive/2012/02/25/chocolatey---guidance-on-packaging-apps-with-both-an-install.aspx